# Can I put an event emitter in a class node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, dom-events

I have a this class:

```
class test {
    constructor(name) {
        this.name = name
    }
}
```

So I want to have a event in the class that can be called outside.

Here the full file:

```
const eventLib = require('events');
const myEmitter = new eventLib.EventEmitter();

class test {
    constructor(name) {
        this.name = name
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can either subclass the EventEmitter so that your class has all the same methods as an EventEmitter object or you can put an eventEmitter in your instance data and can use it there.

Here's subclassing it:

```
const EventEmitter = require('events');

class Test extends EventEmitter {
    constructor(name) {
        super();
        this.name = name
        this.on("hi", () => {
            console.log("got hi: ", this.name);
        });
    }
}


let x = new Test("Bob");
x.emit("hi");
```

Comment: When i enter the code it it say `ReferenceError: Must call super constructor in derived class before accessing 'this' or returning from derived constructor`

Comment: @MaxNguyen - Yes, that is correct. I edited to fix.